# What is the difference between Poll SCM & build periodically in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, cron

In both it takes cron expression as input, so what's the actual difference between these two.

Answer (score 90):

*Poll SCM* periodically polls the SCM to check whether changes were made (i.e. new commits) and builds the project if new commits where pushed since the last build, whereas *build periodically* builds the project periodically even if nothing has changed.

Comment: what happens if we dont mention any cron expression in poll scm ? does it poll scm ?